# UIView Not Rounded, UITableView Cell Recycling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, recycle

I have a **UIView** within the cell of a **UITableView**. My **cellForRowAtIndexPath** rounds that view. When I open the viewcontroller and see the table, all the visible views are rounded. However, when I scroll down, the first new cell to appear does not have a rounded view. How do I fix it?

My **cellForRowAtIndex** looks like this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RepeatingCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
cell.delegate = self
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 0, 0)

if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row < tableListInfo_Context.count {
    let task = tableListInfo_Context[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row                
    let accState = task.value(forKey: "state") as? String
    //Removed assigning labels their text
    let mainView = cell.mainView
    mainView.isHidden = false
    let circleView = cell.viewToRound
    circleView?.isHidden = false
    circleView?.layer.cornerRadius = (circleView?.frame.size.width)!/2
    circleView?.layer.masksToBounds = true           
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 1000, 0, 1000)
} else {
    //My last cell hides several views to reveal a view under them 
    //If I comment this one line out, I get the not-rounded problem only once and it does not show up again even if I continue scrolling up / down 
    let mainView = cell.mainView
    mainView.isHidden = true
    let circleView = cell.viewToRound
    circleView?.isHidden = true
}
```

I understand that **UITableViews** recycle cells and I think that's likely causing me problems. I think it's related to that last cell where I hide views.

In a list of 20 cells, sometimes a non-rounded view shows up as the first to scroll on screen, sometimes the second. As I scroll up/down, randomly a view isn't rounded! I know there's a reason/pattern, but I don't know what.

I also tried adding the rounding code to **willDisplayCell**:

```
let circleView = myCell.mainCircle
circleView?.layer.cornerRadius = (circleView?.frame.size.width)!/2
circleView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

However, that did not solve it. How inconsistent this is is very frustrating. Any help would be appreciated.

FULL CODE AS REQUESTED BY DUNCAN:

```
  func buildCell_RepeatableCell (indexPath: IndexPath) -> CustomTableViewCell          {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RepeatingCell",     for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self

    tableToSV_Left.constant = 10
    tableToSV_Right.constant = 10
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 0, 0)

    if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row < curLifeList_Context.count {
        resetDataCell_ToDefaultLaylout(cell: cell, hideExpand: true)
        let task = curLifeList_Context[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        let accState = task.value(forKey: "state") as? String
        cell.nameLabel!.text = task.value(forKey: "name") as? String
        cell.descLabel!.text = task.value(forKey: "desc") as? String
        let redTrashIcon = UIImage(named: "trash")
        let maskedIcon = redTrashIcon?.maskWithColor(color: .red)
        cell.row5_LeftBtnImg?.image = maskedIcon
        let doneGreen = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 83/255, green: 223/255, blue: 56/225, alpha: 0.9)
        let greenCheck = UIImage(named: "check_Green")
        let maskedCheck = greenCheck?.maskWithColor(color: doneGreen)
        cell.row5_RightBtnImg?.image = maskedCheck
        roundQtyCircle(view: cell.mainCircle)
        if accState == "Selected" {
            cell.circleLine.backgroundColor = doneGreen
            cell.mainCircle.borderColor = doneGreen
            cell.hdrCrossOutLine.isHidden = false
            cell.row5_RightBtnImg.alpha = 0.5
        } else {
            cell.circleLine.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 211/255, green: 211/255, blue: 211/255, alpha: 0.9)
            cell.mainCircle.borderColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 211/255, green: 211/255, blue: 211/255, alpha: 0.9)
            cell.hdrCrossOutLine.isHidden = true
            cell.row5_RightBtnImg.alpha = 1.0
        }
        cell.dataHdr_Left!.text = doneColon_lczd
        cell.dataHdr_Right!.text = lastDoneColon_lczd
        cell.dataVal_Left!.text = "0"
        cell.dataVal_Right!.text = "-"
        if let lastCompDate = task.value(forKey: "lastCompleted") as? Date {
            cell.dataVal_Left!.text = "\(task.value(forKey: "timesCompleted") as! Int)"
            if NSCalendar.current.isDateInToday(lastCompDate) {
                cell.dataVal_Right!.text = "Today"
                cell.dataBotDtl_Right.text = ""
            } else {
                let secondsUntilChange = (lastCompDate.seconds(from: now)) * -1
                print("Seconds ago \(secondsUntilChange)")
                var timeAgo = getDateString(secondsUntilChange, resetDate: lastCompDate)
                timeAgo.remove(at: timeAgo.startIndex)
                cell.dataVal_Right!.text = timeAgo
            }
        }
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 1000, 0, 1000)
    } else {
        buildAddNew_ForRepeatableCell(cell: cell)
    }

    return cell
   }

  func resetDataCell_ToDefaultLaylout (cell: CustomTableViewCell, hideExpand: Bool) {
    cell.addnewBtn.isHidden = true
    cell.nameLabel.isHidden = false
    cell.dataHdr_Left.isHidden = false
    cell.dataHdr_Right.isHidden = false
    cell.dataTopDtl_Right.isHidden = false
    cell.dataBotDtl_Right.isHidden = false
    cell.mainBox.isHidden = false
}

func buildAddNew_ForRepeatableCell (cell: CustomTableViewCell) {
    cell.addnewBtn.isHidden = false
    cell.descLabel.text = addNew_lczd //For editor
    cell.mainBox.isHidden = true
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 1000, 0, 1000)
    cell.container.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: In else block of `cellForRow` method you are hiding `mainView` but you are not unhiding it in the if block.

Comment: @Adeel that was just an error in my removing the text assignment code, I accidentally removed that unhide line. If the mainView wasn't being unhidden, I wouldn't see the non-rounded view at all.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting layer properties of the view in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, set them in your `CustomTableViewCell` class. You can set them in `awakeFromNib` Method.

In short move your below code to `awakeFromNib`.

```
 let circleView = cell.viewToRound
    circleView?.layer.cornerRadius = (circleView?.frame.size.width)!/2
    circleView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

The sudo code could be something like this:

```
awakeFromNib(){
self.viewToRound?.layer.cornerRadius = (viewToRound?.frame.size.width)!/2
viewToRound?.layer.masksToBounds = true  

}
```

Comment: I was excited about this idea but it didn't fix the problem. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Are there any errors after this approach? can you show how you implemented my solution?

Comment: override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        self.mainCircle?.layer.cornerRadius = (mainCircle?.frame.size.width)!/2
        mainCircle?.layer.masksToBounds = true

    }

Comment: try to use  mainCircle?.layer.clipsToBound = true

Comment: If I do not format the last cell differently, the problem goes away. So I think this can be solved by understanding cell recycling, which I guess I do not.

Comment: Just tried it. It's actually mainCircle?.clipsToBound (without the layer). When I scrolled to the bottom, my 2nd to last cell was not rounded. Then when I scrolled back to the top, my top view was not rounded.

Comment: Thanks for pointing my typo about clipsToBound. It seems that your problems is due to mismatch in some indexPaths.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work.

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.viewToRound?.layer.cornerRadius = (viewToRound?.frame.size.width)!/2
        viewToRound?.layer.masksToBounds = true 
    }


override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.viewToRound?.layer.cornerRadius = (viewToRound?.frame.size.width)!/2
        viewToRound?.layer.masksToBounds = true 
    }
```

Comment: Nope. I didn't know prepareForReuse existed. I was pretty excited but that doesn't work either. 90% of the time they are round but still non-round ones appear both when I scroll quickly and slowly.

Comment: Can you share me you source code (sample project) will update and revert you with solution, using same methods in my answer

Answer (score 0):

@Adeel already told you the problem and the solution in his comment.

You always need to fully configure your cells in every case. Remember that when you get a recycled cell, it might be in any possible leftover state.

In your case, the key bit is:

```
if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row < tableListInfo_Context.count {
  //Configure cells that are not the last cell
} else {
  //Configure cells the last cell
  mainView.isHidden = true
}
```

You hide `mainView` in the case where you're configuring the last cell, but don't un-hide it if it's not the last cell. So, if you configure the last cell, scroll it off-screen, then scroll back towards the top of the screen, that recycled cell will get reused for an `indexPath` other than the last one, and it's `mainView` will never get un-hidden.

```
if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row < tableListInfo_Context.count {
  //Configure cells that are not the last cell
  //-----------------------------
  // This is what you are missing
  mainView.isHidden = false
  //-----------------------------
} else {
  //Configure cells the last cell
  mainView.isHidden = true
}
```

@VishalSonawane's answer is good, but to make that work you should use 2 different identifiers, one for all cells but the last one, and a different identifier, with a cell pre-configured with mainView hidden, for the last cell. That way you won't get a recycled last cell and try to use it for one of the other positions in your table view.

Comment: Hi Duncan, I'm sorry to have wasted your time on that but that was just an error in my removing the text assignment code for my SO post, I accidentally removed that unhide line. It is definitely unhidden. If the mainView wasn't being unhidden, I wouldn't see the non-rounded view at all

Comment: We can't debug code we can't see. You should probably show your entire `cellForRow(at:)` method.

Comment: Alright, it's a bit lengthy so I'd tried to not overwhelm everyone but just added it!